# How to get count for each value from json file using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to get the count for a specific value in a `.json` file.

I can get each key, value from the `.json` file, however I cannot get the count of each distinct value related to a specific key.

Here is my json.

```
[{
        "id": "2",
        "first_name": "Jorge",
        "last_name": "N",
        "biography": "Bio Being Updated",
        "image": "staff2.JPG",
        "sort_order": "c",
        "shop_id": "1",
        "title": "Technician"
    },
    {
        "id": "133",
        "first_name": "Larry",
        "last_name": "B",
        "biography": "Bio Being Updated",
        "image": "staff133.JPG",
        "sort_order": "a",
        "shop_id": "1",
        "title": "Shop Manager"
    },
    {
        "id": "150",
        "first_name": "Sean",
        "last_name": "S",
        "biography": null,
        "image": "staff400.jpg",
        "sort_order": "b",
        "shop_id": "2",
        "title": "Technician"
    },
    {
        "id": "160",
        "first_name": "Lori",
        "last_name": "A",
        "biography": null,
        "image": "staff401.jpg",
        "sort_order": "f",
        "shop_id": "2",
        "title": "Booking"
    },
    {
        "id": "300",
        "first_name": "Smith",
        "last_name": "B",
        "biography": null,
        "image": "staff402.jpg",
        "sort_order": "c",
        "shop_id": "3",
        "title": "Writer"
    }
]
```

From the above json, I want to get the count array for each `shop_id`.

For example,

```
console.log('count of shop1 : ', shopCount[0])//output count of shop1 : 2
console.log('count of shop2 : ', shopCount[1])//output count of shop2 : 2
console.log('count of shop3 : ', shopCount[2])//output count of shop3 : 1
```

If you have any idea, please help me.
Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Show what you tried. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert your json to an array object.

For your example, get

```
var shops= '[1, 1,2,2,3]';
var array = JSON.parse(json_ar);
```

and then just count

```
var count_shop= {};
array.forEach(function(x) {
    count_shop[x] = count_shop[x] ? count_shop[x] + 1 : 1;
});
```

so you will get

```
count_shop= {'1': 2, '2': 2, '3':1}
```